Sign convention on thermodynamics - Problem 6.6 Heat and thermodynamics
I made the problem 6.6 of Heat and thermodynamics by Zemansky. But I have a question with the sign of the final result from section c). If I use $W= P \Delta V$ instead $W= - P \Delta V$, my answer is like the book say, but in the chapter 3, Zemansky says the work is $W= -P \Delta V$. So I think the final answer's numerator should be "$1-\gamma$" instead of "$\gamma -1$".
The problem is

And the definition of work is (pag. 53)


Presumably, $0<\eta <1$ since $(\gamma-1)>0$

First of all, Zemansky uses $W=-P\Delta V$ instead of $W=P\Delta V$ because as I recall he uses the following version of the first law for a closed system (used in chemistry)
$$\Delta U=Q+W$$
Whereas the version commonly used in physics and engineering is
$$\Delta U=Q-W$$
The two versions are consistent in that they both result in a reduction in internal energy if expansion work is assigned a negative value for $W$ in the first version and a positive value for $W$ in the second version.
I haven't attempted to solve the problem, but in order for the numerator to be $1-\gamma$ instead of $\gamma-1$,  your final result should be consistent with the fact that  $0\lt\eta\lt 1$ and $\gamma=c_{p}/c_{v}\gt 1$.
Hope this helps.
